# Is there any way to make website responsive without media queries

Tags: css, media-queries

I have a blog: [Creative Blogging Tips](https://www.seebeetee.com). I am trying to make it responsive, but I find it too complicated to interact with `media queries`, it really needs a lot of time.

I am looking for an easier way to make my website responsive. Is there any way to make a website responsive without using `media queries`?

Comment: Nope. Older sites need to be redesigned with mobile and tablet designs in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the only way to do it, without media queries, is using Javascript.

Googling by "javascript responsive layout" I found [ResponseJS](http://responsejs.com/) which seems to dispense handling with media queries.

I also suggest you to look for some CSS frameworks like [Columnal](http://www.columnal.com/) and [1140](http://cssgrid.net/) which makes your job much easier when designing responsive layouts.

Answer (score 7):

There still are percentage widths, max-width, min-width and similar css commands.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Javascript onresize and onload and check for document width and change classes on the body element (or other elements) accordingly.

I think media queries are less error-prone, although you are right about the query syntax being painful and time-consuming.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can make your website responsive without media queries.

Not only that, but the less you use media queries, the easier your websites will be to maintain.
Designing a website to use less media queries is a good design goal. It can be tricky but it's definitely worth the effort.

I strongly encourage you to look into css **flex**, but you can still work with floats, inline-blocks, percentages. It's not too much difficult css wise.

Answer (score 0):

I completely agree, You might be surprised what you can accomplish just using percentages. But i recommend setting the viewport size:
`<meta name=viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`
Using a viewport tag and percentages is a great way to start.

Answer (score 0):

If not media queries then you can use frameworks like bootstrap, skeleton etc.
Also flux, and other css and width and heights in %